# New command entry is not displayed in context menu for xml files

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

i added a new command to my plugin. it should display an entry for text ruler context menu. All is working correctly, it is displayed for all kind of files except for xml files. this is my command:

```
  <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
     <menuContribution
           locationURI="popup:#AbstractTextEditorContext?before=additions">
           <command
                 commandId="com.mycommand.test">
           </command>
     </menuContribution>  
</extension> 

  <command
        id="com.mycommand.test"
        defaultHandler="com.mycommand.test"
        name="This is my command">            
  </command>
```

Some pics:

Other kind of file

[image: Other kind of file]

XML file

[image: XML file]

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Your 'other kind of file' menu looks like the ruler context menu rather than the main context menu. The XML editor is based on the WST StructuredTextEditor which may use a different id for the menu

Comment: Hi greg, thank you for your answer, it helped me to understand, so  i have been looking for this id on the internert, but i couldn't find it. Also i used eclipse spy, but it only displays the id for the editor, not for the ruler.  do you know how can i get this??   Thank you so much for your help.